# How to show total user online OpenCart 2.0x

Tags: opencart2.x

I'm new, 
I want to show how many users (customer & visitor) online. All I could find is commercial extension and it's for older version.

Can anyone point to right direction on this ?

Answer (score 0):

Edit 2:

Add this function in 
opencart22\catalog\model\catalog\category.php

```
  public function getTotalCustomersOnline($data = array()) {
    $sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS total FROM `" . DB_PREFIX . "customer_online`";
    $query = $this->db->query($sql);
    return $query->row['total'];
  }
```

and add the code in 
\opencart22\catalog\controller\common\header.php

```
    $customer_total = $this->model_catalog_category->getTotalCustomersOnline();
echo "Customer Online".$customer_total;
```

---

Edit 1
Opencart already have function to show online visitor/customer (On admin Dashboard)

You can edit code and display on your website

[image]

Tell me if u didn't understand

Comment: Yah, I noticed that, but I'm new at this, so could you point to me where should I dig this method ?